# CSS styles are missing when viewing a page's preview under browser developer tool's Network tab

Tags: html, css, developer-tools, browser-console

When I load a page from my offline website (home page or any other page), the CSS styles appears fine as expected in that loaded page. But right after the page loaded, if I view the same page under browser's network tab (in google chrome, the shortcut key for that is F12), the loaded page and the css file are showing as expected and the status code for that pages are 200 which means the files loaded fine, but the problem is right after the page loaded to the browser, when I click the **preview** of the page in browser developer tool's Network tab, only loaded page content is displaying but the CSS styles of that page is missing inside the preview. Why is that? below is my CSS link.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/mysite/design/style.css">
```